# Split 32 bits integer into 4 parts

Tags: c#, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, bit-shift

i've a byte array of size 16384(SourceArray). i want to split it into 4 parts,4 byte array of size 4096. Now each 32 bits from SourceArray will be divided into 10 bits,10 bits,11 bits and 1 bit (10+10+11+1=32 bits). Taking first 10bits,then next 10bits then 11bits and then 1bit.
lets say for example first 4 bytes from the sourceArray, i get a value 9856325. Now 9856325(dec) =   00000000100101100110010101000101(Binary)-----------------------------
 0000000010(10bits)    0101100110(10bits)    01010100010(11bits)   1(1bit). I cannot store 10,10,11 bits in byte array, So i'm storing it into Int16 array and for 1 bit i can store it into a byte array.
`
I hope problem statement is clear. I've created some logic.

```
        Int16[] Array1 = new Int16[4096];
        Int16[] Array2 = new Int16[4096];
        Int16[] Array3 = new Int16[4096];
        byte[] Array4 = new byte[4096];

        byte[] SourceArray = File.ReadAllBytes(@"Reading an image file from directory");
    //Size of source Array = 16384 

        for (int i = 0; i < 4096; i++)
        {
            uint temp = BitConverter.ToUInt32(SourceArray, i * 4);
            uint t = temp;
            Array1[i] = (Int16)(t >> 22);
            t = temp << 10;
            Array2[i] = (Int16)(t >> 22);
            t = temp << 20;
            Array3[i] = (Int16)(t >> 21);
            t = temp << 31;
            Array4[i] = (byte)(t>>31);
        }
```

But i'm not getting the actual results. i might be missing something in my logic. Please verify it, whats wrong Or if you have some better logic,please suggest me.

Comment: There are some types that may help you, first is `System.Collections.BitArray`: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.bitarray(v=vs.110).aspx and the other is `System.Collections.Specialized.BitVector32` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.bitvector32(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Splitting to 10,10,11,1 you are exploding a 4 byte value (int32) into a 7 bytes value, no? IOW it shouldn't be 4096 but 16384 as the array sizes.

Comment: No,i'm breaking it into 4 bytes array of size 4096. which is 4096*4 = 16384 bytes

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion much easier to process bits starting from the last (least significant bit):

```
uint t = BitConverter.ToUInt32(SourceArray, i * 4);
Array4[i] = (byte) (t & 0x1);
t >>= 1;
Array3[i] = (Int16) (t & 0x7ff);  // 0x7ff - mask for 11 bits
t >>= 11;
Array2[i] = (Int16) (t & 0x3ff);  // 0x3ff - mask for 10 bits
t >>= 10;
Array1[i] = (Int16) t;  // we don't need mask here
```

Or in reverse order of bit groups:

```
uint t = BitConverter.ToUInt32(SourceArray, i * 4);
Array2[i] = (Int16) (t & 0x3ff);  // 0x3ff - mask for 10 bits
t >>= 10;
Array2[i] = (Int16) (t & 0x3ff);  // 0x3ff - mask for 10 bits
t >>= 10;
Array3[i] = (Int16) (t & 0x7ff);  // 0x7ff - mask for 11 bits
t >>= 11;
Array4[i] = (byte) (t & 0x1);  // we don't need mask here
```

Comment: how are you calculating the mask for bits?

Comment: In my mind. It's basics. Read the [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mask_(computing)).

Comment: @Jubatian Huh, fixed. Thank you.